# In a #define clause, how to make the preprocessor replace a parameter inside a variable name?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following code:

```
#define MY_MACRO(PARAM) int PARAM_int; double PARAM_double; [subsequent instructions]
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, meaning that PARAM is not replaced inside the variables names. Is this solvable some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PARAM_int` is considered to be a single token, that is distinct from `PARAM`. You can concatenate tokens in a macro definition with `##`:

```
#define MY_MACRO(PARAM) int PARAM ## _int; double PARAM ## _double;
```

Now, `PARAM` will expand to whatever you invoke the macro with, and then the resulting token will be pasted together with `_int` and `_double`.